# How to remove multiple items from a swift array?

Tags: swift

For example i have an array

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to remove item at index 1 then at index 3 "let it be in a for loop".

But removing the item at index 1 will move the item at index 3 to index 2, thus messing up the second removal.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Given your array

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and a `Set` of indexes you want to remove

```
let indexesToRemove: Set = [1, 3]
```

> You want to remove the values "2" and "4".

Just write

```
numbers = numbers
    .enumerated()
    .filter { !indexesToRemove.contains($0.offset) }
    .map { $0.element }
```

**Result**

```
print(numbers) // [1, 3]
```

Comment: is there any chance you know how to use the same example in Swift 3 ?

Comment: Thanks mate I was trying to do it my self and it didn't work i think i was missing out on something thanks again.

Comment: An alternative to the chained `filter` and `map` is using a single `flatMap`, e.g. `... .enumerate().flatMap { indexesToRemove.contains($0) ? nil : $1 }` (same syntax Swift 2.2/3.0).

Comment: Thank for the info mate (Y) @dfri

Comment: @dfri: I keep forgetting that `flatMap` is the new `filter` + `map` :D

Comment: @appzYourLife I don't know which one I prefer really; `filter+map` possibly shows intent better, whereas `flatMap` can be just a little bit neater (imho) in cases where the operation within the map is somewhat trivial :) good to know both alternatives!

Comment: What does 'offset' achieve here?

Answer (score 13):

It's simple. delete items from the end.

First delete 3 and after that delete 1

Comment: I can't do that when deleting multiple items from a UITableView it is throwing index out of bounds

Comment: @Raffi when you change the data source (the array), do you also `reloadData` on the  table? The table needs to know that the row count is now different.

Comment: Sort the indices array in descending order first. 
indices = indices.sorted(by: {$1 < $0})

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:** Use swift closure to perform the same operation.

If your array is like

```
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and indexes you want to remove

```
let indexesToBeRemoved: Set = [2, 4]

numbers = numbers
    .enumerated()
    .filter { !indexesToRemove.contains($0.offset) }
    .map { $0.element }
and result
```

> print(numbers) // [0, 1, 3, 5]

**Swift 3:**
Here is same operation with JSON Object (dictionary)

```
var arrayString = [
    [ "char" : "Z" ],
    [ "char" : "Y" ],
    [ "char" : "X" ],
    [ "char" : "W" ],
    [ "char" : "V" ],
    [ "char" : "U" ],
    [ "char" : "T" ],
    [ "char" : "S" ]
]

let arrayIndex = [2, 3, 5]

arrayString = arrayString.enumerated()
    .filter { !arrayIndex.contains($0.0 + 1) }
    .map { $0.1 }

print(arrayString)
```

> [["char": "Z"], ["char": "W"], ["char": "U"], ["name": "T"], ["name":
>   "S"]]

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is removing from behind. So you don't have to worry about the changed index.

```swift
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let indexesToRemove = [1, 3]
indexesToRemove.sort(by: >)
for i in indexesToRemove {
    numbers.remove(at:i)
}
```