# How do I address the element position when using filter in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

myData is an array of structs. I want to create a new array omitting the struct **element** in the **second position**.

```
var newData = myData.filter{$0 != 1 } // doesn't work
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to remove multiple items from a swift array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002345/how-to-remove-multiple-items-from-a-swift-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove just 2nd object then instead of filter you can try like this.

```
var newData = myData
newData.remove(at: 1)
```

If you still want answer with `filter` then you can make it like this.

```
var positionThatNeedToRemove = [1, 4, 7]
var newData = myData.enumerated().filter { !positionThatNeedToRemove.contains($0.offset) }.map { $0.element }
```

Comment: @Sean Welcome mate :)

Comment: is there a way to do it  when `positionThatNeedToRemove` is a single integer not an array? This is because I need to chain `.filter` to `.map` and I don't know if I can do that with `.remove`? Guess I should try. Just want to keep this as succinct as possible.

Comment: if it is some Int then it is simply `var newData = myData.enumerated().filter { positionThatNeedToRemove != $0.offset }.map { $0.element }` Also it will better if you show us what you actually want to achieve that will give us more idea